# How to add Public IP to Cent OS

Tags: networking, centos, ssh

I am trying to configure a Public(Static) IP in Cent OS 6.4. For this, I made a copy of eth0(added local IP, so that I can connect the system to Internet) and named it to eth0:0(added Public IP, so that the system can be accessible via SSH).

After restarting the network devices, am still not able to get the required result.

I want to access this system via SSH with the configured public IP.

ifconfig -a

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr EC:A1:6B:7B:89:2C  
          inet addr:192.168.1.55  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::eeb8:6bff:fr7b:892c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:540549 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11533 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:65591743 (62.5 MiB)  TX bytes:1079767 (1.0 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:480 (480.0 b)  TX bytes:480 (480.0 b) }
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:0

```
DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=ec:a1:6b:7b:89:2c
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=93c4dce4-68ab-45c2-a356-1e1da7979502
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPV6INIT=no
USERCTL=no
IPADDR=1XX.1XX.1xx.180
NETMASK=255.255.255.248
GATEWAY=1xx.1xx.1xx.177
DNS2=1xx.1xx.1xx.4
DNS1=1xx.1xx.1xx.5
```

Comment: Tell us about your network situation. How are things connected to the internet?

Comment: Also, can you cut-and-paste the output of `ifconfig -a`, and the contents of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:0` into your question?

Comment: have updated with the details but can't share the Public IPs.

Comment: @MadHatter should be an answer

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing `DEVICE=eth0` to `DEVICE=eth0:0` in `ifcfg-eth0:0`?  Also, remove the `HWADDR` and `GATEWAY` lines; you can't have more than one default gateway.

There may be a more fundamental issue here; we can help you get the ip address on to the virtual interface, but if you don't have the networking infrastructure in place to service that address, not much will come of this.

Comment: I have changed the DEVICE name and removed HWADDR and GATEWAY from ifcfg-eth0:0. But still it is not working. ifcfg-eth0 is directly connected to the Internet which makes the Internet working. I was looking for a solution which can help me access this machine remotely via SSH.

Comment: What happened when you did `ifup eth0:0`?

Comment: That's working, then.  The external IP address is applied to the interface alias, as you asked for.

Comment: Its up but not able to ping as its the public IP.

Comment: As I said, you'll need to make sure that your network topology supports having that address on that interface before it has any chance of working.  You'll also need to sort out routing, NAT, and the like.  They are all outside the scope of this question, and moreover, the question has been closed by the community.

Comment: I have a local machine which is connected to the Internet, and what I am trying to do is just adding a Public IP which can help me access the machine from other locations via SSH. 

Please help me by giving any such solution which can help me to do so. I am a noob to Linux with just basic skills which made me seek the solution. I have no intention to spam such a good forum.

Comment: cyril, I'm sorry, but your system is **not** directly connected to the Internet via eth0, despite what you said in your first comment above, because it has an RFC1918 address (192.168.1.55).  You need to learn about NAT, routing, PAT punchthroughs in your router config, hairpin NAT, and a few other things, to do this.  **What you're trying to do is not simple**, and we can't give you the thorough primer on IP networking basics that you need in the course of a SF answer.  I'm glad you don't intend to spam this forum - so please: take note that your question's been closed, and don't.